# string comparision in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string-comparison

i have a combo box from where i get values and i get the values also correct but when i compare them it is not getting compared and i don't get the results too.

```
if(selectedItems[2] === "Pick Pack"){
                alert("packing Method 1: "+selectedItems[2]);
                global.getElementById("CIMtrek_daily_contact_1").value="";
                global.getElementById("CIMtrek_daily_contact_1").value="chris.dowden@shawinc.com"; 
            }
```

when i printed `selectedItems[2]` it gives me `Pick Pack` but does not get in to the if condition and alert.
I tried to alert but the alert is not coming. Please help me to fix this

Best Regards

Comment: Is it `"Pick Pack"` or `"Pick Pack "`?

Comment: parse selectedItems[2] before comparing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
String.prototype.trim=function(){
 return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
};
```

and

```
if(selectedItems[2].trim() === "Pick Pack"){
                alert("packing Method 1: "+selectedItems[2]);
                global.getElementById("CIMtrek_daily_contact_1").value="";
                global.getElementById("CIMtrek_daily_contact_1").value="chris.dowden@shawinc.com"; 
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
if(selectedItems[2] === "Pick Pack"){
            var data = 'packing Method 1: '+selectedItems[2],
            alert(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using triple === instead of double ==.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the posting. `Abhijeet Pawar` and `Florian Margaine` comments gave me start to fix this issue

the following is the code helped to fix the issue;

```
if($.trim(selectedItems[2]) === $.trim("Pick Pack")){
                global.getElementById("CIMtrek_daily_contact_1").value="";
                global.getElementById("CIMtrek_daily_contact_1").value="chris.dowden@shawinc.com"; 
            }
```